# Exception "read/write protected memory" in byte* to byte[] conversion

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, marshalling

i have to call c++ .dll function and get 16 bytes from it, but has some troubles with it :(

I use the .dll functions by DLLImport as following:

```
public static extern int ZBRGPMF_CCC_Read(IntPtr hPrinter, int 
printerType, byte cardType, byte blockNumber, byte authentication, out 
IntPtr data, out IntPtr dataSize, out int err);
```

Here is description of the .dll function, maybe i also make a mistake in wrapper

> Syntax: 
>   int ZBRGPMF_Read (
>   HANDLE hPrinter,
>   int printerType,
>   byte cardType,
>   byte blockNumber,
>   byte *dataBlock,
>   int *dataBlockSize,
>   int *err)

Basically, by this code under debug (by breakpoint) i'm able to see the data i need and it's correct - BUT, unfortunately if i try somehow operate t this byte* - i have exception "Attempt to read/write protected memory".
I allready tried to use Marshall.Copy.

```
byte[] arr = new byte[16];
IntPtr dataInSector = (IntPtr)(arr[0]);

//pretty sure, this is wrong
IntPtr length = (IntPtr)16;

if (PrinterHelper.ZBRGPMF_CCC_Read(hPrinter, printerType, 0, 
sectorToRead, authentication, out dataInSector, out length, out err) != 
0)
{
    unsafe
    {
        byte* bbbb = (byte*)dataInSector;

        // convert byte* to byte[] here
    }
}
```

I think that i'm using this dll function wrongly, because normally, there should be pointer to the first elemnt of the array - or am i wrong?
Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: That is not likely to be correct.  The function wants you to pass a buffer that it can fill, declare it as byte[] (no out).  And it wants to know the size of the buffer and tell you how many bytes it copied, declare it as ref int.

Comment: Have you tried `Marshal.ReadByte` and `Marshal.WriteIntPtr` instead of Marshal.Copy?

Comment: Yes, man, THANK YOU!

Comment: only i have now array of strange bytes and previously, by using byte* i had exactly hex equivalent of needed data...hmm